# Freebase MQL Query print article?

Tags: freebase, mql

here's my query:

```
[{
  "type":   "/tv/tv_series_episode",
  "series": "The Simpsons",
  "guest_stars": [{
    "actor": {
      "/common/topic/article": [{
        "id":       null,
        "optional": true,
        "limit":    3
      }],
      "name": null
    }
  }]
}]
```

Freebase is returning an id for the article such as: id: "/m/0sw7x", how would I print this ID. I've read that you have to use a "trans" service but I'm not exactly sure how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [trans service](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Trans_services) is actually pretty simple to use. You just append that ID to the end of a GET request and it sends back the article content like this:

```
http://api.freebase.com/api/trans/raw/m/0sw7x
```

I gave a more detailed explanation to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903192/freebase-query-for-full-topic-summary/4903832#4903832).

Answer (score 1):

Or you can fetch the article directly with MQL as detailed in my answer to the question narphorium's pointed at.