# Freebase Java API full text retrieval

Tags: java, freebase, mql

Is it possible to use the "text" MQL extension with the java api, so you can get the full description text.
I mean sth like this:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903192/freebase-query-for-full-topic-summary) but for the java api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **extended** parameter in the query envelope to enable MQL extensions in your query. With the example query that Philip gave in the linked question, that would look like this:

```
JSON query = o(
  "id", "/en/jimi_hendrix",
  "/common/topic/article", a(o(
    "text", o(
      "maxlength", 16384,
      "chars", null
    )
  ))
);
JSON envelope = o("extended", 1);
JSON params = o();
Freebase freebase = Freebase.getFreebase();
JSON response = freebase.mqlread(query, envelope, params);
String text = response.get("result")
                      .get("/common/topic/article")
                      .get(0).get("text")
                      .get("chars")
                      .toString();
```

I should point out that MQL extensions are an experimental feature of the Freebase API and they are not supported in the new version of the API. The new API will provide text either through the Topic API or directly from the Text API.

Comment: Could you tell me the reason that i cannot retrieve the information(text) for some topics( eg. "River Thames" ),while i can for others that belong in the same category( eg. Docklands )??The same things happen with other queries like geolocation( lat/long )..

Comment: Can you share the exact queries that you're using? I was able to get "River Thames" without any issue like this:

JSON query = o(
          "id", "/en/river_thames",
          "/common/topic/article", a(o(
              "text", o(
                  "maxlength", 16384,
                  "chars", null
              )
          ))
      );

Comment: Yes, you're right about the text but what about geolocation?It's not only Java problem: http://tinyurl.com/6d3fj9e

Comment: The short answer is that lat/long haven't been entered for River Thames yet. Please re-post this as a separate question if you'd like a more detailed answer.