# Finding a type description in Freebase?

Tags: api, freebase

I've been trying to get the types in domain person with the following query:

```
[{
  "/type/object/id": "/people",
  "/type/object/name": null,
  "/type/domain/types": [{
    "/type/object/id": null,
    "/type/object/name": null
  }]
}]​
```

but I also want to have a short textual description of the type. Anyone knows what's the property I'm looking for? I've tried looking for it but to no avail. I need a textual description similar to what is shown here: http://www.freebase.com/schema/american_football.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same property (/common/topic/article) that you use for topic descriptions. So your query would look like this:

```
[{
  "/type/object/id": "/people",
  "/type/object/name": null,
  "/type/domain/types": [{
    "/type/object/id": null,
    "/type/object/name": null,
    "/common/topic/article": [{
      "text": {
        "maxlength": 16384,
        "chars":     null
      }
    }]
  }]
}]​
```

[Try it out](http://tinyurl.com/5w63fcm)

Remember that /common/topic/article is a [MQL extension](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL_Extensions) so you'll need to [turn on that feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820106/freebase-java-api-full-text-retrieval) if you're using the API.

**Note:** MQL extensions are an experimental feature of the Freebase API and they are not supported in the new version of the API. The new API provides text through directly from the 
[Text Service](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Text_Service).